# Maven download or fetch the wsdl from the url to project directory

Tags: maven-2

We developed a web service client application using the wsdls from the url location.

I don't want the webservice client to go and validate the actual wsdls everytime , so wanted to download the wsdls in to local project .
is there any way can i download the wsdls using maven similar to copy resources?

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 2):

You can use the wagon plugin to download the files to your project. See its [**usage page**](http://mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Answer (score 0):

Two cases. If you own the service code, and it's something like Apache cxf, there's a command line like java2wsdl or java2ws. In the case of CXF, there's even a maven plugin for the job already.

If the service is 'out there' somewhere, you could use the linux wget or curl commands to fetch the wsdl from the ?wsdl URL.

Comment: wget generates the classes but not downloading the wsdl to local path

Comment: wsimport you're thinking of @user684434