# Keeping WSDL files up to date

Tags: java, web-services, maven, soap, wsdl

I have imported a WSDL web service a couple of months ago and realized that when I call it using the same class files I run into an issue. After a reimport it works again. (Probably significant changes were made to the 3rd party service.)

Is there a a way to automatize this so for example every maven build would re-fetch the class files (if needed) so that we don't have to worry about this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could incorporate this plugin into your build to create classes based on teh wsdl.
http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html

This way based on the WSDL classes will be generated with every build. All you need to do is keep updating the WSDL in the source dir.

Edit: 
Seems like this plugin can also download the WSDL file.

[Maven download or fetch the wsdl from the url to project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625309/maven-download-or-fetch-the-wsdl-from-the-url-to-project-directory)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not not sure that this will be of much help to you, but since I'm in the pretty much the same situation:

- Any way someone has to keep updating the WSDL file. Currently we discuss solution that this WSDL file can be included in build.x.x.x.jar (I have it included in my project too).